# How to use external style sheet in webmatrix

Tags: css, razor, stylesheet, webmatrix

I have a problem with my webmatrix in using an external style sheet,the page still loading and nothing appear,but when I put the css I used in a style tag inside the head tag the problem is solved , but i need to put them in an external file ... how ?

why I faced that problem ?

Comment: What code are you using to link to the external stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything you do differently in WebMatrix for this (except that you may want to prepend the path to your file with a tilde (`~`) which has the effect of telling the server-side code to make an absolute path out of a relative one in ASP.Net Web-Pages [not sure about Web-Forms or MVC]).

You just do this:

**In your HTML Page (in the `<head>` section):**

```
<link href="~/someDirectory/someCSSFile.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then just make sure the css path and file name are correct, and you're good to go.